google chrome developer tools content override not working
I'm trying to override response data in Chrome DevTools (version 124.0.6367.119), but I'm encountering an error. When I right-click on an API call and select "Override content," I receive the following error message: "No resource with given identifier found." There is no additional information provided, and editing the response seems to be disabled.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is this a known bug in Chrome version 124.0.6367.119? Any suggestions for fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

First time coming across this now,  will see if my other browsers give me the same trouble
